# How to sync content data on android devices

Tags: android, file, synchronization

I have a basic question about a showroom application done in android.

how can I sync files, JSON, HTML, jpeg...  on multiple devices. there's a CMS to manage the content. 
I can export this CMS Files to the servers hard drive...  but how can I sync these files to the device. whats the best way to do this.

regards

Comment: Dropbox has an Android API. If using a 3rd party service is not an option (or just not practical), you'll need to implement something yourself -- there's nothing pre-canned to do this for you.

Comment: Create web services for that all and put you all data on Server, you can get from that server.

Comment: which api is usefull to implement something own.